# Can't I run two different JSB functions at the same time?

Tags: cefsharp

//register JSB

```
browser.RegisterAsyncJsObject("afw", new AsyncBoundObject(browser, Application.StartupPath + "\\" + GEDE_CONST.EXE_CACHE_PATHNAME););
```

//AsyncBoundObject.class

```
public i =0;
public string myAdd(IJavascriptCallback callbackFunc){

    for(;i<100;i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        callbackFunc.ExecuteAsync(i);
    }
    return i
}
public void setIvalue(int value)
{ i= value;}
```

//sample.js

```
function cback(data){
   console.log(data);
}
```

**My purpose is**:JSB add "i" per second, and call js to output "i"; and I can't change the value of i while "myAdd" running.

**My question is**:When I call  "myAdd" function, console.log(i) can work; But I can't call setIvalue to change the value of i while myAdd is running. "setIvalue" will run after "myAdd" return.

What should I do ?

CefSharp 49 with .net 4.0

Comment: Version 49 is very very old, you'd have to modify the source to add support for running tasks in parallel. The current version (84) can run tasks in parallel.

Comment: Maybe the new WebView2 from Microsoft better suites your needs?

Comment: A quick look and there is someone maintaining a .Net 4 port of CefSharp at https://github.com/Secbyte/CefSharp.Net40 you'd have to build it yourself,  slightly out of date, much newer than version 49.